# PGP command-line program t be called from script or batch file?

Tags: encryption, pgp

I am seeking a freeware, open-source, or fairly cheap PGP Command Line app which can do PGP file encryption.

It should be a Windows solution, and should be able to be called at the command-line, passing parameters, or using a Batch file.

It should also support all the latest versions of windows and windows servers OS.

Please, no GUI interfaces. I seek just a command-line tool. The smaller the package (less distributable) the better.

Thanks for any help you may provide

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you say specifically **"I am seeking a freeware, open-source, or fairly cheap PGP Command Line app which can do PGP file encryption."** and to me this means you are software shopping. Beep Beep!!

Comment: @McDonald's if you were the Road Runner, that would be Meep Meep!

Comment: @fixer1234 LOL.... I didn't know that but now I do... thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a Windows port of GNU Privacy Guard (`gpg`) at http://gpg4win.org.

Since you want the smallest thing that does the job: the "light" release for version 1.0.9 is only 4MB. See http://files.gpg4win.org/gpg4win-light-1.0.9.exe

Comment: Newer versions of the light version are available at http://files.gpg4win.org/. 
 Alternately you can unzip (7z) the ~25MB installer, and then unzip (7z) the `$TEMP/gnupg-w32...` installer and get a working, portable GPG instance for about 12MB.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that be [GPG](http://www.gnupg.org/)?'

The page I linked above says

> Project [Gpg4win](http://www.gpg4win.org/) provides a Windows version
>   of GnuPG. It is nicely integrated into an installer and features
>   several frontends as well as English and German manuals." That page
>   has a "[Download](http://www.gpg4win.org/download.html)" button that
>   takes you to a list of downloads including [Vanilla
>   installer](http://files.gpg4win.org/Beta/gpg4win-vanilla-2.1.1-git4a72a6e.exe).

Comment: Tried downloading it. One link i ended up getting nothing but C code. The other link was a huge Windows GUI package.  Any ideas, exactly what i need to download to get a command-line binary to do file exncryption? Very hard deciphering the downloads

Comment: GPG uses PGP (RFC4880 - https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4880.txt) "GnuPG is a complete and free implementation of the OpenPGP standard as defined by RFC4880 (also known as PGP)."